# Feature a R&E login option?

Tags: feature-request, login, user-accounts

The research and education sector (worldwide) operate highly homogeneous identity ecosystems (aka identity federations). The community of R&E federation operators conducted a survey in 2009 and then had on the order of 20-30 million users worldwide (see below for a description of them). That was before China and India built their identity federations.

If we could figure out a way to make the technology align with Stack Exchange, would it be interesting and/or useful to feature a login option targeted at that community?

The upside might include lowering the bar for research professionals to contribute (no need to sign up for a new account - just use the campus login you use for everything else).

Thoughts?

---

#### What are Identity Federations, aka Access Management Federations?

They are pools of online id-certifiers used across the university sector around the world. Most countries have one dominant one:  in the UK it's the [UK Access Management Federation](http://www.ukfederation.org.uk/). They act as go-betweens for the universities, and other institutions that want to verify the identity of university members. For example, online journal distributors such as [ScienceDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=FederationURL&_method=display&_type=f&prevURL=http://www.sciencedirect.com/science&_acct=C000228598&_version=1&_userid=12975512&md5=88329647000a11376c65620799462507) use them to authenticate people accessing their journals: as long as my institution subscribes to a journal, I can use my own university login via my federation, and get access to the journal papers, from any pc in the world connected to the internet.

They are not openID providers, but offer a service that is not too dissimilar. One key difference is that any old website can't just authenticate against the service: it has to be an arranged agreement.

Note that these logins are related to, but different from, (inter)-national wifi access logins such as [Eduroam](https://www.eduroam.org).

---

#### What is the concrete proposal?

I ask that if we (the R&E identity community) can come up with a way to make "our" identity federations appear like an openid provider then SE would list that openid provider in the list below the top 3.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about. Do you mean adding another OpenID provider?

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the way that even though I'm a Kent university student I turned up at York university and my phone auto connected to their wifi. No idea what the technology behind that is though

Comment: I think [this PDF](https://refeds.org/docs/REFEDSmap.pdf) might be related.  The [Belnet Federation](http://www.belnet.be/en/services/plus/belnet-re-federation), which seems to be one of the options, seems to suggest there is an associated cost, but details are sketchy

Comment: I can see what's in it for StackExchange. I can't see what's in it for the Access Management Federations though. Any thoughts on that, taht you could edit into the question?

Comment: I'd expect the set of people who have the capability and the drive to contribute good content to SE sites but won't do it because they need a new account to be a small set.

Comment: And, @Louis, some [might even prefer to be anonymous](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106611/is-there-anything-to-be-done-about-the-arrival-of-september)...

Comment: In the Netherlands, some (or all?) universities use https://www.eduroam.org for Wifi access, but I don't know if that also allows for actually authenticating to anything else but the Wifi: *"eduroam allows students, researchers and staff from participating institutions to obtain Internet connectivity across campus and when visiting other participating institutions by simply opening their laptop"*. See also [Where can I eduroam?](https://www.eduroam.org/index.php?p=where) (cc @Richard)

Comment: @Arjan Yes, now that you say it eduroam is what it is here too; clearly even more universal than I had imagined

Comment: @Richard, does it also authenticate you to, say, library systems, if you want to get a book from the York library? Or some student administration if you want to sign up for some lecture there?

Comment: @Arjan I must admit I've never tried

Comment: Voting to close as not clear since OP doesn't seem to be bothered to explain. Three hours are more than enough time.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers, do you think that the specific journal provider can tell the difference between you and someone else from the same university?

Comment: @Arjan yes: ScienceDirect greets me by name when I'm logged in via the UK AMF. So it does at least store a unique identifier for the login: I think I had to associate my name with that identifier on ScienceDirect itself.

Comment: I don't think the technology matters that much @ShadowWizard. Internally most of the federations use SAML but running a gateway would be easy for us. A summary of the status/availability of the federation ecosystem in R&E is at https://refeds.org/resources/. 

eduroam is an example of such a federation (although for network access and not for web access). As an illustration of the scale involved, eduroam is among the most widely announced ESSIDs globally, only dwarfed by things like attwifi and boingo.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers and leif - and what does it have to do with Stack Exchange? That's the part I find most hard to understand.

Comment: I believe it is possible to get more contributors by removing one more step to contributing: having to sign up somewhere or for some having to use your facebook or google account. I agree with @Arjan that some users may not want to use their social accts for everything.

Comment: To be very specific: yes we could make this look like an OpenID Provider.

Comment: 20-30 million users worldwide is of course a significant figure. But if we take out those users who also already have an OpenID account, how many would we have left? Is it then still so significant to the extent that developer effort would be justified?

Comment: That is a difficult question to ask. I think you have to consider the users who may have an openid (eg goog) but are unwilling to use it too. What is the developer effort involved in listing another openid provider in SE? Does it involve a lot of work?

Comment: So you're saying those accounts are OpenID accounts? If so it should simply just work already.

Comment: s/ask/answer/ obvously

Comment: I'm saying we could make them appear as OpenID accounts. This would require work on our side and we'd be happy to do that work if the openid provider could get listed, at least among the "minor" ones below the big 3 so our users would have a chance to find it. Maybe do a PoC and see what happens?

Comment: Okay, then please update your post here to clearly state that is what you want to do.

Comment: Done! Thanks for your guidance @Bart - as you can see I'm new to SE.

Comment: @leifj It might help avoid downvotes if you made it patently clear from the get go that what you are proposing is to add an additional OpenId provider. A title like: "Feature the R&E network as an additional OpenId login provider." Right now you have to read the question to the end to figure out that it is what is boils down to.

Answer (score 3):

As a developer on Stack Exchange, I can tell you that **if** R&E can indeed be used by us as any other OpenId provider, we should be able to add it easily enough.

I cannot guarantee that it will be in that location or be added to all sites, but I can see value in giving it a spot on specific academic sites (say Chemistry, Physics and such).

We already have similar integration on other sites (for example: Steam on the gaming site, Launchpad on askubuntu).

---

However. We are trying to simplify our login/signup pages, not complicated them. Adding yet another featured OpenId provider goes against that.

We can't keep adding OpenId providers to the featured ones - in particular given that Google/Facebook are existing OpenId providers that most people will already be using.

Comment: You can add just an icon under "More login options", no?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - where does it end? OpenSSL. R&E. And more and more and  more? There is a perfectly suitable text area for people who want to use one of the smaller openId providers.

Comment: This becomes a catch 22 - R&E is a _potentially_ large OpenID provider that needs a shot at exposure before we it its worth featuring it or not. Perhaps SE could establish a "trial period" of a year or so to determine if a provider "deserves" an icon or not.